# Copy rows from source sheet to last row of target sheet based on filter using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a source file which contained order details. In source file, there is column named 'Payment Status' which has two status, pending and confirm. So, I want to copy confirm payment orders to the last row of target sheet. I mean, if I change the status of an order from pending to confirm, then it must move to last row of target sheet. (It must not copy to same source file row position. I mean if there are 500 rows are in source file and if I change the status of row 200 from pending to confirm, then it must copy to last row of target sheet even if there are row 201 of source file is already present in target sheet with confirm status, then it must move to last row of target sheet, not above the row 201.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far.
and also the sample data with expected result.

Comment: You tag the question with Excel and VBA, but talk about "App Script" in the header of your question. You need to clarify the environment: **Apps Script** is Google sheets, **VBA** is Excel (desktop) and **Office Script** is Excel (Web).

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const col = sh.getRange(headerRow, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).flat().reduce((a, h, i) => (a[h] = i + 1, a), {});
  if (sh.getName() == "order details" && e.range.columnStart == col["Payment Status"] && e.value = "confirm" ) {
    let ssh = e.source.getSheetByName("source sheet name");
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("target sheet name");
    let vs = ssh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() +1, 1, vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

You need to add headerRow,source sheet name, target sheet name and you can run this function from the script editor so don't do so and then complain that you are getting an error.